# Separate list with coordinates efficiently

Tags: python, list, performance, coordinates, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists containing an index and coordinates, in the form [i,x,y], eg:

```
nodes=[[0,1,1][1,1,2],[2,2,3],[3,2,5][......]]
```

I want to separate this list into smaller lists by coordinates. For example, all coordinates within

```
 0.5<x<2.5 and 1<y<2.5
```

from the list above would give:

```
nodes_1=[[0,1,1][1,1,2]]
```

Currently my code does this like:

```
addNODE=[]
deleteNODE=[]
tl=0.0001
for node in nodes:
   if (((Xmin-tl) <= node[1] <= (Xmax+tl)) and ((Ymin-tl) <= node[2] <= (Ymax+tl))):
       addNODE.append(node)
   else:
       deleteNODE.append(node[0])      
       nodes=addNODE
```

(deleteNODE is another variable I need later in my code)

However, the list over which this iterates is very large. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: *For example, all coordinates within {0* what does this mean?

Comment: Other than `i` is there an order to the nodes and coordinates? Could you use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)? Other than that -- biggest suggestions is likely just use numpy.

Comment: Do you have control over the data structure of nodes btw? You could probably save a fair amount of space by using tuples instead of lists for the nodes. Or namedtuples to make your code more readable. The next question to ask is is this really going to be too slow or might you be trying to optimize it prematurely?

Comment: What is Ymin? I don't fully understand your criteria, probably because of the typo, and I don't understand your implementation either, because it's not complete

Comment: @Dan sorry about the typo, corrected. I have solved the problem using numpy,   
it reduced the time from a couple of hours to a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, the *fastest* and still being a Python program is to use numpy for arrays of this type. The data are standardized to the underlying data (ints in this case) and can be queried very efficiently:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> nodes=np.array([[0,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,2,3],[3,2,5]])
>>> nodes[nodes[:,1]>=2]
array([[2, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 5]])
>>> nodes[nodes[:,1]<2]
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2]])

>>> nodes[(nodes[:,1]>=2) & (nodes[:,2]>3)]
array([[3, 2, 5]])
```

With more information in your question, I can refine my numpy example. Here, I used [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html) to select views of the list that meet a condition. It would be easily modified to your example.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, sorry about the typo. I have managed to implement this using numpy:

        nodes = np.array(nodes)
        mask = (x1<=nodes[:,1]) & (y1<=nodes[:,2]) & (nodes[:,1]<=x2) & (nodes[:,2]<y2)
        addNODE = nodes[mask]
        deleteNode = nodes[~mask]

*(how do I format the coments?)

Comment: Play with your actual problem with numpy and come back with specific questions. I cannot see really what you are asking (if anything) in your comment.